# Yamaha P45 Digital Piano - Can it be made MIDI compatible?

Tags: midi, digital-piano, midi-controller-keyboard

[image]

I'm using a Yamaha P45 digital piano. This digital piano does not send MIDI signals despite having a MIDI port. Is there a way possible by which we can make this keyboard capable of sending MIDI signals? Attaching a pic of the rear panel of the Yamaha P45 digital piano.

Comment: I'm not seeing any midi port, but I do see a To Host [USB] port, which can be used similarly to a midi port, with the appropriate drivers & software. Midi itself would then need to be generated via a dedicated midi interface, from your computer, if you need it to drive other external devices.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes

You have to download the USB MIDI drivers and then you can connect the P-45 to a computer to control software synthesizers and/or record and play back MIDI data. If you want to control other hardware using MIDI, you will have to connect that hardware to the same computer.

This page has driver and manual downloads for the P-45:

https://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical_instruments/pianos/p_series/p-45/downloads.html

Answer (score 2):

I currently use a p45 as a controller for soft synths in my pc daw and hooked to my ipad works well with both with just plugging a usb cable into the device. I usean old printer cable I had lying around the studio usb type b to type a cable. the daws recognizes it as a digital piano. the stand alone synths in ios recognize it also.
peace.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it to control other MIDI enabled gear without a PC, you can still do it with a MIDI USB Host.

Careful: **NOT** a USB MIDI Interface.
Disambiguation:

An example could be: https://www.thomann.de/gr/kenton_midi_usb_host.htm

You can find cheaper ones, however I've seen some comments that they sometimes not work or e.g. don't support MIDI Clock or get stuck & such. I know it's expensive, but I don't think there's a cheap alternative.

If you can tingle with programming a bit, you can always experiment and build one with a Raspberry PI and a USB MIDI interface (for example: https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=19736) but I doubt if it's worth the fuss, especially if you're not experienced with Linux & programming.

Answer (score 1):

From a review "Unfortunately, the available controls are not enough to turn the P-45 into a real master keyboard, but at least the built-in USB port allows you to save money for an external USB/MIDI interface and compensate for the ordinary lack of a built-in audio recorder, which is surely a shame for a 2015 product."
https://www.digitalpianoreviewguide.com/yamaha-p45-review/

The answer then is no. But if you want to use it to send midi signals to a program in your computer, use the USB port. You might redirect the Midi signal inside the computer to a Midi interface connected to the computer. In that case the answer would be "sort of".

Comment: The same review says, “t shares all the core-functions with the older Yamaha P-35, adding some new interesting features like the USB connector, which allows you to use the piano as a MIDI controller”. So I’m a bit confused by your assertion that the answer is “no”.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Midi as originally designed is sent on a five pin connector directly between musical instruments. The piano does not have any such connector. Instead it has as USB port which allows you to connect it to a computer (not directly to other Midi instruments). This allows you to control software instruments inside the computer using Midi signals. So if you want to control instruments in a computer it is no. If you want to control other Midi instruments the answer is basically no (unless you buy a Midi interface for the computer).

Comment: Back in the day, multi-keyboard rigs might use direct (5-pin) MIDI connections between several keyboards, maybe with simple MIDI routing or (rather less simple) MIDI Merge and Split boxes.   Now there is invariably a computer as a central routing device, and the 5-pin cables are being replaced with USB connections. Which work both ways, sending and receiving MIDI data.  One keyboard can still 'play' another keyboard.  But there needs to be a computer in the middle.

Comment: invariably? no. I want to use this to drive a hardware workstation without starting up a computer. 'invariably' means without variation, without exception, so you claim to know everyone else's use case without exception?

Answer (score 0):

Page 18 of the manual says **YES**

https://www.musikkhandel.no/media/files/2496/p45_en_om_a0.pdf

https://www.musikkhandel.no/media/files/2496/p45_en_om_a0.pdf#page18

„By connecting a computer to the [USB TO HOST] terminal, you can take advantage of various music software with your computer and the instrument.
For details on using a computer with this instrument, refer to the “Computer-related Operations” on the website.„
„Setting the MIDI Transmit Channels
In any MIDI control setup, the MIDI channels of the transmitting and receiving devices must be matched for proper data transfer. You can specify the channel on which this instrument transmits MIDI data. To do this, while holding down [GRAND PIANO/FUNC- TION], press one of the D6 – E6 keys. The D6 key decreases the value by 1, the E6 key increases the value by 1, and the D#6 key restores the default value (channel 1).
[USB TO HOST] terminal“

But:

**D#6 (Default)
D6 (-1) E6 (+1)
USB cable
• Use an AB type USB cable. When connecting a USB cable, make sure that the length is less than 3 meters.
Computer
• In Dual, the keyboard performance via Voice 1 is transmitted on the specified MIDI Transmit Channel and the keyboard performance via Voice 2 is transmitted on the next channel number in sequence (specified channel + 1).
• No MIDI messages are output during playback of the Demo Song or Preset Song.
Other MIDI Settings
The MIDI settings other than the Transmit Channel are set as listed below, and cannot be changed.
MIDI Receive Channels: ....................................... All channels (1 – 16)
Local Control: ............................................On Program Change Transmit/Receive:........Yes Control Change Transmi**

Answer (score 0):

with ACID music STUDIO 11, i can use Yamaha P125 like a midi keyboard through many VST available with ACID music STUdio 11. I don't know how is it possible..but i can record some keybord parts with many other sound out my Yamaha P-125. Sailer didn't tell me that ! (just turn "Digital piano" in device )