# Yamaha P45 MIDI Capabilities / What are the requirements for controlling this keyboard with my computer?

Tags: midi, keyboard

Prefacing this post with a link to a post covering the same topic, but I'm having a hard time understanding if any of these solutions allow me to use my computer to change the instruments and manipulate sounds.

[Yamaha P45 Digital Piano - Can it be made MIDI compatible?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/67143/yamaha-p45-digital-piano-can-it-be-made-midi-compatible)

If I'm understanding correctly, if I hook my computer up via usb to midi, the most I will be able to do is play and record something on the keyboard, and listen to it on my computer.

Other comments refer to using the keyboard as a controller. Does this mean only the keyboard can talk to and tell the computer what to do? Versus my computer telling the keyboard what sounds to play and what velocity/pitch to play it at? Will I see recordings as an audio clip or MIDI clip where I can see and change what notes are being played?

What are the minimum requirements a keyboard needs to meet in order to control the sounds, instruments, and effects from my computer? I am currently using an Alesis MIDI keyboard and looking to upgrade. Since my Alesis has this capability I am surprised to see that the Yamaha doesn't.

My current setup is keyboard connected to computer, and computer connected to speaker via AUX. While the Yamaha has internal speakers, I would rather hear it from mine in addition to the other sounds I am playing along with. in Ableton

Thank you for your help, I think I just need a dumbed down explanation of the post I linked to understand. Best, and thanks again

Answer (score 1):

MIDI is a way for musical instruments to communicate with a device and tell it what notes they're playing. If you're using MIDI, then you need to get your own instrument sound on the computer via something called a VST. You can change the VST currently active to change the instrument.

If you just want to play the sound on your own speakers, you can just connect a cable from the headphone jack to your speakers. Not sure how to get both the sounds from your computer and the keyboard to play.

> Does this mean only the keyboard can talk to and tell the computer what to do? Versus my computer telling the keyboard what sounds to play and what velocity/pitch to play it at?

As in using the keyboard to play back a MIDI file or some MIDI input? I'm honestly not sure. But the other way round (keyboard tells the computer what notes it's playing) is supported.

> Will I see recordings as an audio clip or MIDI clip where I can see and change what notes are being played?

As a MIDI clip.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](https://usa.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/8/333228/p45_en_om_a0.pdf#page=18), the keyboard has MIDI receive capabilities as well.

If it's implemented as it ought to be, this should mean you can specify it as a MIDI output in your DAW.

Here's an example of a track in Reaper that is routed to UM-ONE (my USB-to-MIDI cable), which connects it to my keyboard. The keyboard then plays the data in whatever voice I have it currently set to. As a bonus, I then record the keyboard audio output so that I don't have to have my keyboard on in future just to hear the track — obviously can only be done once the MIDI is finalized.

[image: routing]